# over order by rows with variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-order-by

Is there a way to use a variable as a dynamic number in the formula below so I can reset the 4game_so_ct number to zero when the opponents change in the id column.  I've tried to order by id as well and that just puts them all in order by id obviously and doesn't reset the number.  The column 4game is the number of preceding rows to look at to get the previous number of rows where the id is the same.

```
 sum(strikeouts) over (order by game_dt rows between 3 preceding and current row) as 4game_so_ct
```

what I tried

```
 sum(strikeouts) over (order by game_dt rows between 4game preceding and current row) as 4game_so_ct
```

but it errors out obviously.

I have a table like below

```
GAME_ID         GAME_DT HOME_TEAM_ID    AWAY_TEAM_ID    id  strikeouts  4game   test    4game_so_ct
WS1192204120    19220412    WS1              NYA      NYAWS1    4          0     0       4
BOS192204180    19220418    BOS              NYA      NYABOS    2          0    NYAWS1   2
NYA192204210    19220421    NYA              WS1      WS1NYA    1          0    NYABOS   1
NYA192204220    19220422    NYA              WS1      WS1NYA    2          1    WS1NYA   2
NYA192204230    19220423    NYA              WS1      WS1NYA    0          2    WS1NYA   0
NYA192204250    19220425    NYA              PHA      PHANYA    1          0    WS1NYA   1
NYA192204260    19220426    NYA              PHA      PHANYA    4          1    PHANYA   4
NYA192204280    19220428    NYA              BOS      BOSNYA    0          0    PHANYA   0
NYA192204290    19220429    NYA              BOS      BOSNYA    6          1    BOSNYA   6
NYA192204300    19220430    NYA              BOS      BOSNYA    4          2    BOSNYA   4
NYA192205010    19220501    NYA              BOS      BOSNYA    2          3    BOSNYA   2
NYA192205020    19220502    NYA              BOS      BOSNYA    1          4    BOSNYA   1
```

what I would like to see in the 4game_so_ct column

```
GAME_ID         GAME_DT HOME_TEAM_ID    AWAY_TEAM_ID    id  strikeouts  4game   test    4game_so_ct
WS1192204120    19220412    WS1              NYA      NYAWS1    4          0     0       4
BOS192204180    19220418    BOS              NYA      NYABOS    2          0    NYAWS1   2
NYA192204210    19220421    NYA              WS1      WS1NYA    1          0    NYABOS   1
NYA192204220    19220422    NYA              WS1      WS1NYA    2          1    WS1NYA   3
NYA192204230    19220423    NYA              WS1      WS1NYA    0          2    WS1NYA   3
NYA192204250    19220425    NYA              PHA      PHANYA    1          0    WS1NYA   1
NYA192204260    19220426    NYA              PHA      PHANYA    4          1    PHANYA   5
NYA192204280    19220428    NYA              BOS      BOSNYA    0          0    PHANYA   0
NYA192204290    19220429    NYA              BOS      BOSNYA    6          1    BOSNYA   6
NYA192204300    19220430    NYA              BOS      BOSNYA    4          2    BOSNYA   10
NYA192205010    19220501    NYA              BOS      BOSNYA    2          3    BOSNYA   12
NYA192205020    19220502    NYA              BOS      BOSNYA    1          4    BOSNYA   13
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Syntax diagrams can be a bit hard to follow.  But the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql) is clear that the window frame specification needs to be a constant:

> ```
> <window frame preceding> ::=   
> {  
>     UNBOUNDED PRECEDING  
>   | <unsigned_value_specification> PRECEDING  
>   | CURRENT ROW  
> }  
>  . . .
> <unsigned value specification> ::=   
> {  <unsigned integer literal> }
> ```

Hence, you cannot do what you want with a windows frame specification.

Answer (score 1):

You are over complicating it. Use a `partition by` in `SUM` which is what the expected result is.

```
sum(strikeouts) over (partition by id order by game_dt)
```

Comment: I agree. This will get you exactly what you want.

Comment: It's not resetting to 0 though the next time those 2 teams play.  I tried that fomula as well.  Later in the year PHA plays NYA and it grabs the five from the row you see in the data and adds the 3 strikeout a month later.  I want the games played a month later to reset to 0.  This formula would work if I could figure out a way define a "series" for each specific chunk of games.

Comment: but the question doesn't show that..please post all the details in the question.